# Refresh the page without reloading with a shared variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I can't solve this problem for a week. It is necessary to update the page of the mini-chat on the laravel. There will be very few requests - 5-15 users per day with and 5-7 requests from each, so it was decided to do it using jQuery+Ajax. But the problem is that the updated part depends on the main content:`

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <div id="update">
   
  </div
@endforeach
```

Script

```
script>
    function message()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{asset ('message')}}",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#update").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        message();
        setInterval('message()',10000);
    });
</script>
```

File **message**:

```
 $messages=Message::whereUserId($user)->orWhereSenderId($user)->get()
      @foreach($messages as $message)
        {{$message->message}}
      @endforeach
```

And of course the file needs a variable  $user. Can it be passed on? How practical is this?
This file is shown as a display principle.Many thanks for any thoughts and ideas. Thanks!!

Comment: _Unrelated fyi_: you'd have multiple elements with `id="update"` - which is invalid, `id`s need to be unique.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !!! It is inaccessible to make such mistakes !!! I'm trying now `<div id="update-{{$user->id}}">`  and `$("#update-{{$user->id}}").html(html);`